# How to make this animation run smoothly using react and svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have the following component:

```
class Ball extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { frame: 0, position: this.positionBall(0) };
    this.nextFrame();
  }

  nextFrame() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      frame: prevState.frame + 1,
      position: this.positionBall(prevState.frame + 1)
    }));
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.nextFrame());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <circle
          cx={this.state.position}
          cy={this.height() / 2}
          r={this.radius()}
        />
      </svg>
    );
  }

  height() {
    return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }

  width() {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  }

  radius() {
    return this.height() / 10;
  }

  positionBall(frame) {
    const maximumPosition = this.width() - 2 * this.radius();
    const maximumFrame = 120;
    const slope = maximumPosition / maximumFrame;
    const position = Math.round(
      maximumPosition +
        this.radius() -
        1 * Math.abs(frame % (maximumFrame * 2) - maximumFrame) * slope
    );
    return position;
  }
}
```

It is a very simple animation, but it doesn't run entire smooth all the time, especially on wide screens. How can I improve this code?

See this codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/22kzjy21n